# Contact Form Submitting but nothing received

Tags: php, contact-form

Hey i have a basic contact form which is submitting but nothing is being received.

I have set the form to load a template if successful, which it does.

The code below is my form code

```
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" id="name" >
            <input name="customer_mail" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="customer_mail">
            <textarea name="detail" placeholder="Message" id="detail"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="button" name="Submit2" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

and this page is my submission page

```
 <?php

 //Include the common file
 require_once('common.php');

 // Details
 $message="$detail";

 // Mail of sender
 $mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

 // From 
 $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

 // Enter your email address
 $to ='EMAIL ADDRESS REMOVED';
 $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// If message sent..
if($send_contact){

//Display the template
$tpl->display('send-contact');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}           

?>
```

I have tried sending it to and from two different email addresses and check for any filters on the email addresses themselves but i'm still unable to send my contact form.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you encounter any errors?

Comment: Have you configured SMTP on your Apache server ?

Comment: Where are `$detail`, `$customer_mail`, `$name` and `$subject` defined?

Comment: You probably don't have `register_globals=on` in your php.ini, which is (overall) good. Use $_POST['postedVarName'] instead.

Comment: @PatrickManser Don't just remove spaces for readability. Especially spaces before `<?php` are suspicious.

Comment: To add to @matcarlson: don't just put `$_POST` variables in your headers, as you will be prone to mail header injection (spammers can inject multiple mail addresses and thankfully use your form to send spam).

Comment: @PatrickManser There are no errors shown.
Marcel - i assumed they were defined in the submission page, is that not correct?

Comment: No, those variables are not automatically defined, as @matcarlson already wrote.